# Simple Web-App for Recording and Analysing Job Application Forms

Tags: web-apps, open-source

I have been asked to develop a website (a web database) to record the statistics of unemployed people. the general requirements are as follows

- Filling and submitting a form including, age, education, skills....
- Search, grouping, sort or prioritize  persons according their information (need, education ...)
- Security
- Tracking of information and status
- Analyzing tools to get some statistics of the number of unemployment in different areas...
- I don't want it too complex to extend (Maybe WordPress is too complex and has too features for my purpose)
- Easy to translate to other language (internationalize)

I am searching an Open Source CMS, Job Board, Portal or any web application in PHP and Mysql to offer such features

In summany, I can say I am looking for a simple cms which offer secure database features or a simple robust extendable form processing and analyzing web application

Any Suggestion?

Comment: Do you need to install it on your own server? Or is a free hosted service OK?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I can host it on my own server

Comment: Google Docs can be used to create forms, collect data, do statistics; however it is not a correct answer because it does not run on your own server, right?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I think so! i need it on my server, and the audience of my website are Persian (Iranian). I need usability and simplicity and internalization, but I check it

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Thank you, I checked it , at least now I know what I am looking for, its a survey system, and somehow I found I can embed the form in my website. it seems a solution I should try it more.